# need to use jhipster generated entities, etc from standalone application

Tags: spring, hibernate, liquibase, jhipster

Using Jhipster I have successfully configured and running angularjs application fine from front end. I have created many custom entities also successfully. Now, in the project I want to have a load.java file and make use of those created entities to load the data from csv files to those entity tables. I mean with out using front end (Angulars), I should be able to use to all the created entities and crud operations from load.java, is it possible to do it? If yes, any sample code reference would be helpful, i did not find any documentation on this part on the website.

Answer (score 0):

CSV loading in JHipster is done through Liquibase at database initialisation.
if you want to load CSV at any time you'll have to code it yourself using the repositories generated by JHipster and this is pure Spring data/JPA question not JHipster specific.